# javafx trying to add multiple lines to path for animation but only 2 lines are formed

Tags: java, javafx

javafx trying to add multiple lines to path for animation but only 2 lines are formed.And if I add lines in loop changing moveto everytime to new x and y then on path transition animation it moves in one line and reverse and then move to new line.Please help I am new to javafx.

```
private Path generateCurvyPath(final double pathOpacity)
       {
          final Path path = new Path();
          int x=10,y=50;
          ArrayList<LineTo> line=new ArrayList<LineTo>();
          TreeMap<Integer,Integer> hmap=new TreeMap();
                    for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
                    {
                        Random rand=new Random();
                        int x1=rand.nextInt(50);
                        LineTo l1=new LineTo(x,y);


                        hmap.put(x, y);
                        line.add(l1);
                        x=x+x1;
                        y=y+x1;
                    }
//        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(10,50));


                    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(100, 100));
//                  path.getElements().addAll(line);
                    for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: hmap.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                        System.out.println(entry.getValue());

                    path.getElements().addAll(new LineTo(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));
                    }

                    path.setStrokeWidth(1);
                    path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

          path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());
          System.out.println(path.getElements());

          return path;
       }
```

Comment: Describe the desired result. Right now your path starts at point `(100, 100)`, moves to point `(10, 50)` and from that point just leads to the right and down at a angle of 45° since you always increment the x and y coordinates by the same value. The last line of the path simply closes it...

Comment: I want n number of lines and move object on that path.Can you give me Idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Technically you're moving the object on n=8 lines. It just happens to be lines that all point in the same direction making it look like a single line...

Comment: And How can i make them in a different direction.When I was changing moveTo everytime then my animation wasn't working as desired.Due to moveTo Animated object moved to previous location and then goes to next line?